# How can I access properties inside objects inside other objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, object

I am trying to access the text property of each object stored in an array. The array is a value of another property, results, inside an object.

I retrieve the object from a server using jQuery, like this.

```
       $.ajax({
       url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
       cache: false,
       type: 'get',
       async: false,
       success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
       });
```

The log statement at the end is to see what I am receiving. Naturally this is where I need to be doing something, but I can't seem to crack the code. So, I have an object with the result property and Array value. The array is an array of objects, each with their own properties. I'm just a bit confused on how to get what I need. Perhaps a gentle nudge in the right direction?

```
Object {results: Array[10]} //object returned

results: Array[10] //value is an array of objects

0: Object           // object '0' expanded...

createdAt: "2013-10-15T19:13:43.576Z"<br><br>
objectId: "uzGerloXA7"
text: "RoboChat: I'm sorry Dave, I can't allow you to do that." // I need this!
updatedAt: "2013-10-15T19:13:43.576Z"
username: "RoboChat"

1:Object   // and I need it for each of these objects.
2:Object
3:Object
etc...
9:Object   //this is the last object.
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a tool like Firebug for Firefox which will allow you to set breakpoints and examine objects. It's great for learning as well as debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
data.results[0].text
```

`[]` will let you get an individual element of an array

`.` will let you get properties of any object.

You'll probably want a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; ++i) {
    console.log(data.results[i].text);
}
```

Comment: To help clarify for me, my thought is that 'results' is a property with one value, an array with 10 objects. If it only has one value (and that value has 10 properties- each with some corresponding values), then how is it possible to use bracket notation on 'results'( ie, why doesn't result[1] return undefined, since there's only 1 item, an array). Your code works I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: To expand, in my brain it should be data.results.array[i].text. Why is this wrong?

Comment: @keith The first message you see in the log is saying that what you're logging (data) contains one property, called results, which is an array with ten elements in it. Once you're dealing with the array, of course, indexing to ten should make more sense. It may make more sense if you play more with your console, e.g. type `data.results`, and `data.results[3]`.

Comment: Thanks Scott, for the answer and for the feedback. Of course, 'results' _is_ the actual array. I don't know why I wasn't getting that. The problem was a lack of understanding the relationship between properties and values I suppose, because now looking back on it, the question (and answer) is actually very simple. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the array index followed by the property name:

```
data.results[0].propName;
```

To iterate, you could do:

```
//Iterate the array of objects
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    //Iterate over the keys of a specified object
    for (var key in data.results[i]) {
        if (data.results[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
            console.log(data.results[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: jslint would complain about not having `hasOwnProperty` check ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could do some iteration like :

```
   var allText = [];
    $.each(data.results,function(i,obj){
      allText.push(obj.text);
    });
```

and all texts are stored in allText ah and its jquery moe

Comment: that's assuming the use of jquery however

Comment: indeed - that's a fair assumption :)

Comment: John, from the info in the question `data` appears to contain just one thing, a property called `results` that is an array of objects. In any case you should say `this.text`, because `$(this).text` would get a reference to jQuery's `.text()` method...